# discord.js PMing users by command through mentioning

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I am trying to create a command where it has a bot PM the mentioned users following the prefix a pre-typed message. How would I do this?

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you mean a command like !pm @user hello there.... And the bot pms sad user saying "hello there"?

Comment: I do mean a command like that, however, instead of typing the actual message itself, all I do is type a couple of letters that represent the actual message, which is pre-typed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late response. Fell asleep after asking for clarification in my comment. Just make an object to map your keys (letters) to the messages.

```
let messageObject = {
    ab: "This is a message that sent from the keyword ab.",
    vd: "This is another message that sent from the keyword vd",
    test: "And a third diff message that sent from the keyword test"
};

client.on("message", message => {
    if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("!dm")) {
        let args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1);
        let user = message.guild.member(args[0].replace(/[<@!>]/g,"")).user;
        let keyword= args[1];

        if(keyword in messageObject){
            return user.send(messageObject[keyword]);
        }
        return message.channel.send("That is not a valid keyword!");
    }
});
```

Comment: I've tried your code out and for me, it appears that it isn't working. My bot isn't pming me at all.

Comment: Are there any errors thrown? You can link me to your entire code except the bot token @Christopher

Comment: There is a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Replace' of undefined"

Comment: Oh my bad, forgot quotation marks. Edited my answer, try again? @Christopher

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest version of node and discord.js. Using mentions was added in a fairly recent update to discord.js

```
bot.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "pm")) {
    for (let user of message.mentions.users.values()) {
      if (message.content.includes("a couple letters")) {
        user.send("pre-recorded message");
      } else if (message.content.includes("different letters")) {
        user.send(" a different pre-recorded message");
      }
    }
  }
});
```